# Yup and internationalization

Tags: reactjs, i18next, formik, yup

I have a React example app with a form made with Formik and a validationSchema made with Yup, but I need to change messages for every language supported.
So I used react-i18next for the internationalization and it works fine.
I have a common namespace and a specific namespace for my "formik-messages".

I just have a question, the Chrome console shows me a warning when I use the ${min} interpolation in my specific-language messages, even if everything works fine.

Example:
My password field has this validationSchema:

password: Yup.string().min(8, t("yup:password-min")).required(t("yup:password-required"))

The namespace is yup and the message is 
"password-min" : "Password must contain at least ${min} characters"

The message is shown with no problems but the Chrome console shows that warning (Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string) because of that interpolation.

Is there a way to do this without showing that warning message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, just using Template literals instead of double quotes

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use i18n in a variable in React application rather than a component  we can use 'i18next' instead of using useTranslation hook from 'react-i18next'

```
import * as yup from 'yup'
import i18n from 'i18next'

const MyValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().when('$name', {
  is: true,
  then: yup
    .string()
    .required(i18n.t('name.validation.nameRequired'))
  otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
  }),
})

export default MyValidationSchema
```